# Class Methods and Properties not getting displayed in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a Web API project in which none of the class methods and the properties are getting shown as tree list (structure) in Visual Studio. Even the .Net classes are not getting loaded. I am encountering this issue only in this project. Other projects from the same solution is working fine. Please find the screen shot for more info
[image: sual][image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by upgrading my Nuget package of DotNetCompilerPlatform to 2.0.1 and I removed the Import Project Tag which was mapping to old DotNetCompilerPlatform version in csproj file.

After this everything is working as normal like other projects.